# ThrowCards in python

Tags: python

Given is an ordered deck of `n` cards numbered `1` to `n` with card `1` at the top and card `n` at the bottom.

The following operation is performed as long as there are at least two cards in the deck:

- Throw away the top card and move the card that is now on the top of the deck to the bottom of the deck.

My task is to find the sequence of the last `k` discarded cards and the last remaining card.

- Each line of input contains two non-negative numbers

  - `n`, where `n ≤ 5000`
  - `k`, where `k < n`
- For each input line produce two lines of output.

  - The sequence of k discarded cards
  - The last remaining card.

  See the sample for the expected format.

Sample input

```
7 2
19 4
10 5
6 3
4000 7
```

Output for sample input

```
Last 2 cards discarded: [4, 2]
Remaining card:  6
Last 4 cards discarded: [2, 10, 18, 14]
Remaining card:  6
Last 5 cards discarded: [9, 2, 6, 10, 8]
Remaining card:  4
Last 3 cards discarded: [5, 2, 6]
Remaining card:  4
Last 7 cards discarded: [320, 1344, 2368, 3392, 832, 2880, 1856]
Remaining card:  3904
```

My code will keep printing out the exact answers but with None on the following line.
I am so confused why it will print None after each output.

Here is my code:

```
def throw_card(n,k):
    lst=[]
    bst=[]
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        lst.append(i)

    while lst[0]!=lst[1] and len(lst)>1 and n<=5000 and k<n:
        bst.append(lst.pop(0))

        if len(lst)==1:
            break
        else:
            lst.append(lst[0])
            lst.remove(lst[0])

    print('Last',k,'cards discarded: ',bst[n-(k+1):])
    print('Remaining card: ',lst.pop())

print(throw_card(7,2))
print(throw_card(19,4))
print(throw_card(10,5))
print(throw_card(6,3))
print(throw_card(4000,7))
```

my output:

```
Last 2 cards discarded:  [4, 2]
Remaining card:  6
None
Last 4 cards discarded:  [2, 10, 18, 14]
Remaining card:  6
None
Last 5 cards discarded:  [9, 2, 6, 10, 8]
Remaining card:  4
None
Last 3 cards discarded:  [5, 2, 6]
Remaining card:  4
None
Last 7 cards discarded:  [320, 1344, 2368, 3392, 832, 2880, 1856]
Remaining card:  3904
None
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: I suggest using the data type `collections.deque` (pronounced "deck" and meaning "double-ended queue") to handle your deck of cards. It's optimized to allow fast insertions and removals from both ends (at the cost of slower operations in the middle). Since all you ever do is `append` and `pop(0)`, it will do exactly what you need, and will be more efficient than a list can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `print(throw_card(7,2))`, you are printing the return value of your `throw_card` function. Your function does not return anything (aka `None`)

What you should do is just call your function.

```
throw_card(7,2)
throw_card(19,4)
throw_card(10,5)
throw_card(6,3)
throw_card(4000,7)
```